# "Please come see me in my office" Reply

Tags: email

How to reply politely to a short email from professor, "Please come see me in my office."? Can I email back and say, "Noted. Thank you." Thanks.

Comment: This is a request from your professor for you to go to his office. This requires an action on your part.  "Noted" is used for acknowledging things that require no explicit action.  You should reply, "Ok, I will come see you during your next office hours" (Or whenever you plan to do it.) Alternatively you could say, "Ok. When would you like me to come?" Also, "Noted" in general is short and dismissive.  I would not recommend ever using it with your professor.

Comment: If the message is literally "Please come see me in my office" you should (as best one can say without knowing the prof) regard it as a *command* to appear as soon as reasonably possible, and you should reply with a statement of your plans to see him -- three o'clock, during your office hours, first thing tomorrow, etc.

Comment: Will you provide me with an example of a request. Depending on the mood and what kind of person you are, there are different ways to respond. For example, if you are more of an audacious type person, and if the request seemed...seductive, you would probably reply with a question for attending earlier than the given time. If you weren't that kind of person you might reply with a simple "ok, I'll make sure I'll be there."

Comment: This is a good question for [The Workplace Stack Exchange](http://workplace.stackexchange.com).

Comment: @Eva Aye aye, sir! ;-) http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/Aye+aye%2c+sir

Answer (score 4):

I think we're overthinking this.  The proper reply is to just go to the office during the professor's office hours.  The only reasons to email are if you can't make it there before the next class or if emailing to schedule an appointment is standard procedure for your department.

Saying "Noted, thank you", creates more doubt about you going then if you'd said nothing.

Comment: There is no proper reply without any context. The OP is asking how to reply "politely" by e-mail. "Just to go to the office" doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @Rathony We've been given a context. A professor has summoned you without explanation as to why. "Just go to the office" is a proper response.

Answer (score 2):

Avoid using "Noted." As noted in the comments, "noted" should be used only when (a) you are acknowledging that you understand what the speaker said, (b) no immediate action is *required* from you (although action may be recommended), and (c) you are speaking formally but to someone of equal or lower "rank." Compare with how the word "Roger" is used in the military to acknowledge a command. If a subordinate responds with "Roger," he/she is saying, "OK, I understand what you are saying, and I will comply." It is short but complete and respectful. "Noted" doesn't carry the same depth of meaning and is less polite.

If you are able to go more or less immediately, I would go right then, and avoid the need to reply to the email at all. That is the short answer, and the one I would lead with if this question were on the Workplace Stack Exchange.

But you asked about how to respond "politely" (and presumably via email specifically). Since the email was short, your reply can be short. Your choices are some combination of one or more of the following:

- State your intention to go.
- State that you are en route.
- Request a specific time/date/location.
- State when you intend to go.

I'll list some examples, *but please keep in mind* that it really depends on using the right tone that feels comfortable coming from you and is comfortable in the context of your relationships with your professor.

> On my way. Talk to you in a minute.
>
> No problem. I'll see you at your next office hours.
>
> Sounds good. I'll be there no later than 3pm.
>
> Of course. See you soon.
>
> I have class until 3pm; I will swing by immediately after.
>
> I'll be there. Would 3pm work for you?
>
> I'm out of town all day today. Would you mind if I came by around noon tomorrow?

Comment: That is a helpful summary and explanation, +1.